# Estimate the type of wavelet transform in receiver side

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, wavelet, waveform-similarity

Suppose that a signal is decomposed by using discrete wavelet transform (DWT) and transmitted. Is it possible for receiver to find which type of wavelet is applied in transmitter side ?

I mean, if the signal is decomposed by Haar or DB and then reconstructed. Is it have any way to know the type of wavelet (like haar) that is already used ?